# How can I store the user's input for future uses?

Tags: python, journal

I'm making a "journal" or "diary" program on Python.
Its very simple, you write the date and then the diary entry and you can read it whenever you want and you can keep adding notes or new entries.
Now, I want to store the user's input so that when he enters the next day, he can read what he wrote and write a new entry for his/her diary but I can't find the way to do it.
I can't find this question on StackOverflow, sorry if it was already asked.

Comment: Do you have any reason not to use a text file for this?

Comment: Nope, im new to programming so im making simple stuff.

Answer (score 0):

writing to a text file:

```
    # \n is a newline.
    date = "23/3/2014 \n"
    entry = "this is my diary entry \n"
    f = open("diary.txt", "a") # a means append, this stops new data overwriting old
    f.write(date)
    f.write(entry)
    f.close()
```

reading from a text file:

```
    g = open("diary.txt", "r") # r means read-only, you cannot write to file that is opened like this
    entries = g.readlines()
    g.close()
    for each in entries:
        print
```

The only difficulty you will have is parsing the file when reading it if you even need to do that but that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: thanks! i didn't understand your other answer, sorry :P

Comment: i dont know if you care :P, but i modified the code and the added some loops and now it works like a charm :)